# Gerrit - Internal server error while pushing to gerrit for review

Tags: git, push, gerrit, review

I've gerrit-2.11 installed in my server and I was testing email notification by pushing some changes to gerrit for review. After a number of pushes it started throwing following error.

```
$ git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
Counting objects: 4, done.Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 289 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 2, done
To ssh://user@host:29418/project
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (internal server error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://user@host:29418/project'
```

I've a number of projects hosted on this server. Now I'm getting the above error for all projects while trying to push something for review. I can see following exceptions in the gerrit error log.

```
[2015-05-26 08:25:07,797] ERROR com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits : Can't insert change/patchset for project
com.google.gerrit.server.git.InsertException: Error inserting change/patchset
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits$1.apply(ReceiveCommits.java:269)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits$1.apply(ReceiveCommits.java:260)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$MappingCheckedFuture.mapException(Futures.java:1809)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractCheckedFuture.checkedGet(AbstractCheckedFuture.java:85)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits.insertChangesAndPatchSets(ReceiveCommits.java:803)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits.processCommands(ReceiveCommits.java:588)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.git.AsyncReceiveCommits$Worker.run(AsyncReceiveCommits.java:89)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator$5.call(RequestScopePropagator.java:222)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.util.RequestScopePropagator$4.call(RequestScopePropagator.java:201)
        at com.google.gerrit.server.util.ThreadLocalRequestScopePropagator$1.call(ThreadLocalRequestScopePropagator.java:55)
```

*

Comment: Does Gerrit have permissions to access the repositories?

Comment: Yes gerrit have the permissions to access repos. Even though I'm getting these error messages, a review is getting created in gerrit and I can review and submit it. But I think these error messages and exceptions will have an impact for sure.

Comment: I have the same issue too...

Answer (score 1):

Please check your remote Gerrit repository with this command to check if your can access your Gerrit repository with username name **user** and hostname **host**

```
ssh -p 29418 user@host
```

I guess that the account to access gerrit is not correct or the hostname of gerrit server is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

If your using ssh, try this before the `git push` command:

```sh
eval `ssh-agent -s` && ssh-add
```